# Difficulty in interpreting the output of tensorflow's dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a LSTM cell based RNN in tensorflow. I have a sequence of words in each row which forms the features and a column named labels (which is either 1 or 0) that serves as the target. I am facing difficulties in interpreting the outputs of `dynamic_RNN`. The `dynamic_RNN` returns the outputs and the states. 
I have split my data in to batches of 256. I have padded/sliced off 
each row to have a uniform length of 160. I then embedded them(using glove) so that each word becomes a hundred dimensional vector. After this my each example turns into a 160 by 100 matrix, and each batch to the RNN function becomes a tensor of shape - (256, 160, 100). Now given that the hidden_dimension of LSTM cell is set to 300, the expected dimension of the hidden state vector for each example(of size 160 x 100) is 1 x 300. However, when I check the shape of `rnn_states.h`, I get the following -

```
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(300)])
```

I was expecting the dimensions to be 256 x 300. I am not sure how to proceed further.

I am adding some code below that I used and their shapes. I have two tensors -  `train_context` and `train_utterance`. I pick 128 samples of each, embed and concatenate them later to form an input batch of 256. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
train_context.get_shape()
# TensorShape([Dimension(128), Dimension(160)])

train_utterance.get_shape()
# TensorShape([Dimension(128), Dimension(160)])

context_embedded = tf.cast(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_W,\
train_context, name="embed_context"), dtype = tf.float64)

utterance_embedded = tf.cast(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings_W,\ 
train_utterance, name="embed_utterance"), dtype = tf.float64)

context_embedded.get_shape()
# TensorShape([Dimension(128), Dimension(160), Dimension(100)])
utterance_embedded.get_shape()
# TensorShape([Dimension(128), Dimension(160), Dimension(100)])

inputs = tf.concat(0, [context_embedded, utterance_embedded])
inputs.get_shape()
# TensorShape([Dimension(256), Dimension(160), Dimension(100)])

cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(300, forget_bias=2.0, use_peepholes=True,\ 
state_is_tuple=True)

cell.state_size
# LSTMStateTuple(c=300, h=300)

rnn_outputs, rnn_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float64,\
parallel_iterations=64, time_major=False)


rnn_states.h.get_shape()
# TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(300)])
```

I am not able to figure why the dimension is None x 300. I was expecting it to be 256 x 300. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`get_shape` is best effort. In general, Tensorflow does not always know the sizes of Tensors at graph construction time. `None` simply means the dimension is unknown at construction time.

The only guaranteed way to find the shape of a Tensor from Python is to run the graph (e.g., via `session.run()` or `.eval()`) to evaluate a Tensor to a specific value, whose shape you can inspect.

(If you want to consume the shape within the graph, there is also `tf.shape`.)

Hope that helps!